# Trying to sort two numbers in descending order using a swap statement using c language

Tags: c

I have to sort the integers in descending order using a swap statement so far i have this but its not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int round, num1, num2;
for (round =0; round <= 3; round++)
printf("Enter two integers: \n");
scanf("%d, %d", &num1, &num2);
printf("The numbers in descending order:  %d, %d\n", num1,num2);
return 0;
}
void swap(int num1,int num2)
{
if (num1 < num2);
swap (num2, num1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're much more likely to be able to help you if you take a crack at the problem yourself and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Check the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more information on asking the right questions. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: I don't see you making swap anywhere in your code.

Comment: In particular, there are a couple of issues with this code - you're never calling `swap` and `swap` itself isn't doing anything (except possibly calling itself again). These are pretty easy to check - compare what you're doing against examples and see what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

hint: Use a temporary variable to swap numbers.

```
int temp;
temp = num1;
num1 = num2;
num2 = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    if(*a < *b) {
        int temp;
        temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *a = temp;
    }
}
```

To call this from main:

```
swap(&num1, &num2);
```

And for the sake of your program's readability, your function shouldn't be called `swap`.  It should be called `sortDesc` or something that actually describes what it's doing.  A function called `swap` should swap the two values unconditionally, but you intend to sort two values according to a condition.

Comment: im new to this so sorry if its not correct but it keeps telling me [Error] invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive] any idea what causes this

Comment: You'll have to edit the code in which you've implemented this into your question so I can see how you've actually implemented it.  And certainly you're getting a line number reference to the line throwing the error?

Comment: You forgot to dereference a and b in your code segment. It should be `int temp = *a; *a = *b; *a = temp;`

Comment: okay this is where im at now void swap(int *num1, int *num2)
{
    if(&num1 < &num2) {
  int temp;
        temp = *num1;
        *num1 = *num2;
        *num2 = temp;
    }
}

Comment: That's not what I have in my answer.  Specifically, you have the condition of the `if` statement wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your `swap()` function is wrong because in C function arguments are passed by value. So changes made in called function are not visible in function that makes the call.

The second problem is you never call your swap function in main(), so how is it supposed to swap anything, anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do without using temporary variables.

```
num1 = num1+num2;
num2 = num1-num2;
num1 = num1-num2;
```

Hope you like swapping numbers now :)
Happy coding!

Comment: This is not proof against overflow if the integers are signed and the values are big enough.